# An American TV series about human-like aliens

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I watched this TV series in the late 80s or maybe the early 90s, it was subbed in Arabic

Most likely it was American and it was not animated, I believe its from the same era of [Small Wonder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088610/).

I don't remember that much about it but it involved a group of aliens who live among us **secretly** , they look just like us however I cant remember if they could shape-shift or not. One distinctive thing I remember is that they could jump very high (due to the different gravity) when nobody was looking since they are from an other planet.

There was at least two men and I think of them at least was working a police officer or something like that and he used his powers once to sort out problems/crimes when nobody was looking. Sadly that's all I can recall

Edit: I think I remember they had a massive ship in the outer space

Edit2: I have check all the shows mentioned in the answers and comments including V original miniseries, sadly it's none of them.
I'll assume that my memory is bad and the show is not American nor in English. I don't think it's from the 80's most likely from the 90's

Comment: Do you remember if this was a thriller, comedy, drama, etc?  Also, any idea what the length of the show was?  (1/2 hour?)

Comment: Sci-Fi, 30-40 minutes

Comment: I can think of a couple, though one is a mini-series and the other is from the 2000s. Are these possibilities?

Comment: It might be a mini-series but not from the 2000s, I also think it's might not be American but certainly it was in English and not dubbed

Comment: I'm assuming it's not the original [V](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086822/)?

Answer (score 9):

I wonder if you're after [Galactica 1980](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080221/combined), a spin-off of the original *Battlestar Galactica* that was cancelled after 10 episodes. Airing in 1980, it featured the Galactica crew members reaching modern day Earth and trying to blend in. They looked human, but some of them could leap to great heights because of the differences in gravity. There were also plenty of shots of their mothership in space.

All 10 episodes are currently on Youtube, if you want to check them out. Here's the intro:

Comment: 1980 only got 10 episodes? Wow I thought it got atleast a full season. Then again I only saw a single episode, the Halloween one with the skin job Cylon

Answer (score 2):

you are thinking of Hard Time on Planet Earth

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like Alien Nation, which started in 1988.  The human-like aliens do live among us, but they're out in the open, though there is also open discrimination against them.  One of the aliens is a police officer and has a human partner.  They can jump high, as I recall.  Here's the [IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096531/).

[image]

Comment: This isn't a TV series

Comment: The Newcomers in _Alien Nation_ don't "look just like us"--they were clearly identifiable from the lack of hair and spotted skin patterns, nor did they live secretly (pretty impossible, really), but were out in the open. The show was all about the integration of an immigrant population.

Comment: @Pasta It was a movie and a TV series.  The TV series had 22 episodes.  I just included the wrong IMDB link in my answer.  I'll change it so it points at the TV show!

Comment: @inkista Good points. I wasn't sure about my answer, but I included it since the OP's memory was a little hazy ("I don't remember that much about it..."). That's also why I started my answer with "This sounds a lot like" instead of "I know the show you're looking for." It will be up to the OP to tell me whether I was completely off base, or if his memory had added details that weren't really there originally.

Answer (score 1):

I'll toss in a guess though the police officer teamed up with an alien girl. She's humanoid and is trying to track down a xenomorph, a shape-shifting alien which escaped the prison ship on which she worked. He has been trying to find a serial killer~the escaped alien. The two of them visit the massive spacecraft in orbit during their pursuit.

Something Is Out There (1988 TV miniseries and series spinoff)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Is_Out_There

The series couldn't capture the feeling of the miniseries, which still holds up quite well. In some ways, it resembles "The Hidden" (1987). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_(film)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like ***Earth: First Contact***. The cop was human with alien organism/equipment on his arm. The aliens were distinct looking, and a season or two in, the main character that took over ended up being a hybrid with tri stand DNA.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [Roswell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0201391/?ref_=kw_li_tt)  it is an American science fiction television series,  debuted on October 6, 1999. it was about a human/alien hybrids, sent here to complete their destiny, a destiny given to them by the members of their dying race, a race that they are someday destined to save

Comment: Certainly not, sorry

Comment: What about X Files:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106179/?ref_=kw_li_tt

Answer (score 0):

Could it be "3rd Rock From The Sun"? It started in 1996, but it is about aliens looking like humans.

> A group of aliens has come to Earth to learn about its population,
>   customs, etc. To avoid detection, they have taken on human form which
>   gives them human emotions, physical needs etc. WITHOUT the
>   understanding of what they mean or the inhibitions normally present in
>   humans. Their leader takes the position of a college professor, their
>   military expert as his sister, their intelligence expert, supposedly
>   oldest of group takes form of his teenage son. The uninhibited
>   reactions turn everyday events into unusual situations.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115082/

Answer (score -1):

You are talking about [The Invaders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders)